# Custom UIActivityViewController with Background and Items

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to make a custom UIActivityViewController. I saw this one in the Litely app:

[image]

and really like it. It has a "night theme".  So how do I change the background color and how can I add custom items to it?  Thanks!

Comment: Please do not add the Xcode tag to your question. It does not apply to the question.

Comment: Considering "Instagram" is the first sharing service listed, this is obviously a 100% custom implementation (Instagram is not a system-supported sharing service like Facebook and Twitter). This looks pretty simple though, just two `UICollectionViews` / `UIScrollViews` on a blurred `UIView` which was probably presented using the new UIViewController Transition coordinators. Then a nice little X button. Of course, you'd have to implement each service in your code.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that it's a custom implementation.  Can you show some code as an example?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot customize the existing iOS widget.  If you want a custom one, you must build a custom one.

[Here is one](https://github.com/brantyoung/OWActivityViewController) of many open source implementations on GitHub.